# hcitool starts working and then sputters out

Tags: unix, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

On my Raspberry Pi, I've installed Bluez and I'm running the command:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

which returns output like this:

```
4C:0C:F7:63:33:CB (unknown)
8C:85:90:63:A9:29 (unknown)
```

In the first 5 seconds I get 10+ results. Then it suddenly sputters out -- I barely get 2-3 results every minute! 
How can I fix this?

Comment: I figured it out! No more sputtering. I need to include duplicates, which adds duplicates and a lot of valid results that I was missing. It looks like the default setup of suppressing duplicates was overactive. Here's the code that works: `sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates`

Comment: General feedback, use DBUS as long as it is available. This is recommended since Bluez5.